# What is different between intent and listener?

Tags: android, android-intent

what is difference between the 'Intent' and 'Listener'? 
i am not getting right answer from google. can any one explain me for the reference.

Comment: What do you mean by Listener?

Comment: are yaar listener actionListener, onClickListener like that.

Comment: @Viraj.S sir he knows very well about Listener (as you defined) PM is asking again because both are completely different... and here you are trying to compare.. :)

Comment: I am new in Android and i have only knowladge of Java and there is no intent type in java. so i am bit confused and that's why i have asked this question..

Answer (score 1):

An intent is a class. Intents, in the Android platform, make up the major communication protocol for moving information between application components. In a well-designed Android application, components (activity, content provider, or service) should never directly access an instance of any other component.

An event listener is used to process events.

Answer (score 0):

A `Listener` object is the "implemantation" of an `Observer` [pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Intent is a class